# Not able to read blob as arraybuffer in C++ addon in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I'm trying to POST a blob object from client written in angularJS to NodeJS server. I'm successfully receiving the message.

client side code is something like

```
var imgData = [/*about 8K of data read from file*/];
var blob = new Blob([imgData], { type: 'application/octet-binary'});
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.addEventListener("loadend", function() {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", "https://xyzabc.io");
    request.send(reader.result);
});
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
```

I have written a C++ addon as described in https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html
. when i'm trying to parse the arguments it detects attached data as v8::Object & not v8::arrayBuffer.

```
void RunCallback(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
    if (args[1]->Isobject()) {
        //console.log('Not what i was expecting');
    }
    if (args[1]->IsArrayBuffer()) {
       //console.log('this is what i'm looking for');
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?? I blob not supposed to be send that way??
I took client side code from https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Blob

Comment: Can you show serverside code?

Comment: Anyway, http://bespin.cz/~ondras/html/classv8_1_1Value.html.
In node v4, new Buffer will create Uint8Array, by default, so try this args[1]->IsUint8Array().

Answer (score 0):

In my module i'm did this like:

```
if (node::Buffer::HasInstance(args[1])) {
   //this is buffer
}
```

And it's ok for node v4.